# strange output using ctx-simplify tactic

Tags: z3

Small example is prepared below:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Type1 a b c d e g h i f k l m n o p q r s t u v w z)))
(declare-const x Type1)
(declare-const y Type1)
(assert (and (= y x) (or (and (not (= x g)) (not (= x a))) (and (or (not (= x g)) (not (= x q))) (not (= x a))))))
(apply ctx-simplify)
```

The output is:

```
(goals
(goal
  (= y x)
  (or (not and) (not (= x a)))
  :precision precise :depth 1)
)
```

What `(or (not and) (not (= x a)))` means? Bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. 
I agree it looks strange with the "and" taking no arguments in the printout.
The context simplifier creates a conjunction with 0 arguments. 
It gets printed as simply "and". 
So the expression returned by ctx-simplify is equivalent to (not (= x a)). 
I will update the ctx-simplify tactic to return expressions without the empty conjunction.